# how to pass variable through a href tag

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, href

i have a website that provides chat service. i made member-information page for every member in chat. i want to display member-information to anyone who clicked at username in chat.

for example:

```
jack
hi
jhon
hi
jack 
i'm jack
jhon
i'm jhon
```

here is the header

```
$chat_messages_html .= '<li>' . '<span class="chat_message_header">' . '<a href="meeting/member_info">' . $chat_message->username . '</a>'
```

my problem how to get variable $chat_message->username in member information page to use it to retrieve information

i hope it is clear

Answer (score 5):

Add user id to link:

```
$chat_messages_html .= '<li>' .
                       '<span class="chat_message_header">' .
                       '<a href="meeting/member_info?userid=' . $userid . '">' .
                       $chat_message->username .
                       '</a>'
```

Then you can retrieve user id using `$_GET["userid"]` in `meeting/member_info.php`.

And please consider using `htmlspecialchars()` to escape dangerous content.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it through the query string:

```
'<a href="meeting/member_info?username="' . $chat_message->username . '">' . $chat_message->username . '</a>'
```